# Is there a more compact and elegant way to write this code?

Tags: php, optimization

### The question.

I like simple and elegant code and this feels like anything but. The first solution is just gross. Functional and probably reasonably performant but gross. The second is more elegant but seems like overkill for something that should be so simple.

### Setup.

`$recurring` is an array of about 20 items. I have to map these 7 values (days of the week) to a single field. Finishing both of these items with `new_days = implode(',', $days);` or using them in array form depending on where this function is called.

### Try 1

```
  $days = array();
  if ($recurring['m'])
  {
    $days[] = 1;
  }
  if ($recurring['t'])
  {
    $days[] = 2;
  }
  if ($recurring['w'])
  {
    $days[] = 3;
  }
  if ($recurring['h'])
  {
    $days[] = 4;
  }
  if ($recurring['f'])
  {
    $days[] = 5;
  }
  if ($recurring['s'])
  {
    $days[] = 6;
  }
  if ($recurring['u'])
  {
    $days[] = 7;
  }
```

### Try 2

```
  $map = array(
    'm' => 1,
    't' => 2,
    'w' => 3,
    'h' => 4,
    'f' => 5,
    's' => 6,
    'u' => 7,
  );
  $days = array();
  foreach ($map as $offset => $value)
  {
    if ($recurring[$offset])
    {
      $days[] = $value;
    }
  }
```

### Any better ideas?

### Edit: Additional info

The array looks something like this:

```
$recurring = array(
  'id' => 27,
  'end_date' => '12-27-2005',
  'frequency' => 'W',
  'm' => 1,
  't' => 0,
  'w' => 1,
  'h' => 0
  'f' => 1,
  's' => 0,
  'u' => 0,
);
```

With other optional parameters.

Comment: This should go on code review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @chris85 Seems a bit silly. This is code optimization which stackoverflow has a tag for.

Comment: I'd go for Try 2, with the `map`.

Comment: Deleted my answer, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a switch statement and cycle through them..

```
foreach($recurring as $key => $value){
      switch($key){
          case 'm':
            $days[] = 1;
            break;
          case 't':
            $days[] = 2;
            break;
          case 'w':
            $days[] = 3;
            break;
          case 't':
            $days[] = 4;
            break;
          case 'f':
            $days[] = 5;
            break;
          case 's':
            $days[] = 6;
            break;
          case 's':
            $days[] = 7;
            break;
      }   
  }
```

for try 2:

```
foreach($recurring as $key => $value){
      switch($key){
          case 'm':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 't':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 'w':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 't':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 'f':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 's':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
          case 's':
            $days[] = $value;
            break;
      }   
  }
```

Hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

> Any better ideas?

Whether this is better is a matter of taste, but at least it's different:

```
$recurring = array(
  'id' => 27,
  'end_date' => '12-27-2005',
  'frequency' => 'W',
  'm' => 1,
  't' => 0,
  'w' => 1,
  'h' => 0,
  'f' => 1,
  's' => 0,
  'u' => 0
);

$days = $recurring;
array_splice($days, 0, 3, 0);   # replace leading 3 elements by one element 0
$days = array_keys(array_filter(array_values($days)));
```

It reduces the given array to the days' elements (plus a leading `0` to give the wanted day numbering from 1 on), changes the keys to indexes, filters the elements to keep the `1`s, and takes the remaining indexes, which are the wanted day numbers.